# what is the equivalent xml file for layout xml in magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout

How to write the corresponding layout xml file in Magento 2?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <catalogsearch_result_index>        
    <reference name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <setTemplate>tagalys_search/filter.phtml</setTemplate>
        </action>
    </reference>
      <reference name="content">
        <reference type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result">
            <reference name="search_result_list">
                <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <template>tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                 </reference>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 every layout handle is its own file.
So you don't have one big file for a module, you have many smaller files.

In you case the file should be `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml` with the content:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <setTemplate>tagalys_search/filter.phtml</setTemplate>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
        <!-- Not sure of the rest of the code because it's looks strange. Too many references -->
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Basically `reference` becomes `referenceBLock` or `referenceContainer` depending on what you are referencing.
Containers in M2 are `core/text_list` blocks in M1 (content, left, right,...)

Comment: Thanks buddy, and for the referenceContainer,                                            <reference type="catalogsearch/result" > is used in /skin/js/myjs.js as: search: {  link: function(q, qf) {return '/catalogsearch/result/index/?'       and   <referenceName="search_rsult_list" is used in controllers/CatalogSearch/ResultController.php as            $productlist = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list')->toHtml();

Comment: How to give referenceType and referenceName within referenceContainer?

Comment: I am not even aure whar referenceType does

Comment: and <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">   ?    Should i replace with referenceBlock as above ?